# ASP.NET Windows authentication to another Active Directory domain

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication

We have ASP.NET web application running on Server1. Server1 is in Windows Active Directory domain  Domain1.

We would like to have users setup in Domain2 to be able to access our web application using Windows Authentication against Domain2. **ANY user who can authenticate to Domain2 should be able to access our application.**

**Domain1 and Domain2 are on the same LAN but there is no trust or any other relationship between these 2 domains.** Computers from Domain1 can route to and access computers from Domain2 (and the other way around) - there are no firewalls between domains.

Can this be done? I found this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx but it seems all domains have to be in the same forest which is not the case for our setup:

> ... **Step 3. Configure the Web Application to Use ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider**
>
> Identify all the domains that your application supports in your Active Directory forest ...

Comment: Some form of trust between domains must be established. Either at the AD level or you can setup two ADFSes and federate them at the application level and then federate your app with one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't.  There must be a trust in place.