# iis - windows auth via multiple domains

Tags: iis

I’ve got a server at a client setup in a test domain.  Let’s call it domain a.  We want to allow several test users to access the application for testing purposes.  They are in domain b.  There do not appear to be any trust relationships between domain a and b.  The application uses windows with.  I don’t have admin rights to anything in either domain there.
Questions: 
is there a way to allow a user from domain b into our application easily?

Does a trust relationship need to be setup between the two domains to get anything to work?  I think so, but I don’t have the authority to do this so getting this done is going to be really hard.

TIA.
Wally

Comment: Pretty sure it has to be trusted.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458373/asp-net-windows-authentication-to-another-active-directory-domain?rq=1

Comment: Trust relationship will be the best option for you. Otherwise, your application needs to convert credentials from one domain to credentials to another domain itself, which is technically complicated to implement and maintain.

Comment: Thanks.  You are pretty much confirming what I thought.  :-)